# RFD ImageMagick Library installation with composer

Tags: namespaces, imagemagick, composer-php

I installed the RFD ImageMagick Library using

```
composer require rfd/imagemagick
```

I went through the readme and this is how they have done it

```
use Rfd\ImageMagick;
use Rfd\ImageMagick\CLI\OperationFactory();
use Rfd\ImageMagick\Image\File;
use Rfd\ImageMagick\Options\CommonOptions;

$im = new ImageMagick(new OperationFactory());
```

It throws Class 'Rfd\ImageMagick' not found error. But that error goes away when I do

```
use Rfd\ImageMagick\ImageMagick;
```

The statement below throws an error but works with the () at the end

```
use Rfd\ImageMagick\CLI\OperationFactory();
```

Now its giving OperationFactory not found error. I can't find that class anywhere in the install so I'm really confused! Any help would be really appreciated. I'm trying to generate PDF thumnail image previews using this library.

Comment: Open an issue with [author](https://github.com/rfdy/imagemagick/issues). This library seems young, and my have experienced internal refactoring that may not have been communicated with documents/release notes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to  emcconville, I contacted the author. This works

```
use Rfd\ImageMagick\ImageMagick;
use Rfd\ImageMagick\CLI\Operation\Factory as OperationFactory;
```